# .NET Core MSTest Parameters

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest

I have a .NET Core MSTest library, and I would like to pass a parameter to it on the command line. Something like this:

```
dotnet test -myparam=myvalue
```

How would I do something like this, and how would I retrieve the value of "myparam" in code.

Note: I would be ok with somehow specifying a configuration file for the test library to use, rather than just passing a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.runsettings` file to send custom parameters. For example, I could have the following run settings file:

```
<RunSettings>
  <TestRunParameters>  
    <Parameter name="foo" value="bar" />  
  </TestRunParameters>  
</RunSettings>
```

You can then access it through the `TestContext`:

```
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Assert.AreEqual("bar", TestContext.Properties["foo"]);
}
```

Finally, you specify the `runsettings` file on the command line using the `--settings` argument:

```
dotnet test --settings test.runsettings
```

Note: There is support for passing some `runsettings` parameters in via the command line, but it looks like the support is rather basic at this time and it appears that you can't pass `TestRunParameters` in this way.